# Relation between minimal polynomial and divisibility

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix with rational elements and $p$ a prime number such that $A^p = I$ with $p<n$. If $\det(A-I)\neq0$
it is true that $p-1$ divides $n$?
Here is what I've worked so far.

$$A^p = I,$$ so $$(A-I)(A^{p-1}+A^{p-2}+\cdots+A+I) = 0.$$ Since $A-I$ is invertible we can multiply by its inverse and get that $$A^{p-1}+A^{p-2}+\cdots+A+I = 0.$$ We know that the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides this polynomial of degree $p-1$. I do not understand why this implies that $p-1$ divides $n$.

Comment: Related: [An integer square matrix of prime order has size at least $(p-1)\times (p-1)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096696)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The minimal polynomial divides $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\dots+x+1$. However this polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbf Q$ (it is the $p$-th cyclotomic polynomial), hence it *is* the minimal polynomial.

Now the characteristic polynomial has the same irreducible factors as the minimal polynomial, which implies it is a power of the minimal polynomial if the latter is irreducible, so that its degree $n$ is a multiple of the degree $p-1$ of the minimal polynomial.